# Skype video chat - how to enlarge self-video

Tags: skype, conferencing

When video chatting on Skype, self-video is on bottom left corner and it's usually very small. Is there any way to make it same size as remote video? Or is there any other recommend video chatting client?

Comment: I have the same problem with Skype for Mac. What is your OS? You can try ooVoo video chat.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the 'cleanest' solution but it works.

While you are talking you can go to: **Tools -> Options -> Video settings**

Then you will see a button labelled "Take a video snapshot". Click that and It will give you an enlarged version of your video.

You can then close the Options window to get it out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making it full screen, then *both* videos are bigger?  sorry, can't think of anything... :(

Comment: yup, not satisfied with it. I want both screen same size. If possible, I want both adjustable. Thanks.

Comment: @Stan bit late on this but it took me a while to get fed up. So did you ever find a solution for having the video chat windows at same size (large)